# Send message directly without presenting MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Currently,I am developing an app to track iPhone, so when the app is starting, the current location is automatically sent to the Recipient as a text message.

I have used the below code for sending message, but it is for `MFMessageComposeViewController`. I have no idea about how to send message without presenting `MFMessageComposeViewController`. So need some guidance on how this can be achieved. Here is the code :

```
 NSArray *recipents = @[@"8866210464", @"9276820096"];
NSString *message = locationString;   //String for current Location

MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate=self;
[messageController setRecipients:recipents];
[messageController setBody:message];

[self presentViewController:messageController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible. This is to protect the user's privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Apple won't allow to send SMS without user interaction.

I've alternate solution of this, out of scope of iOS:

> *Use web service API. Create a web service at server side that send a message to specific number(s) that accept numbers as parameters with request.*

At specific time interval (according to your requirement) send a web service call with number as request parameter.

Web server can do it. It can send message to any device.